Can't Build Query Mongocxx C++
I am trying using MONGO DB C++ driver, and I am trying search my database if there is a field that equals a specific string.
The following code below works (implying I have mongoDB C++ drivers for installed correctly
void viewMongoDBServer()
{
    cout <<"Check Mongo Connection" << endl;
    // Establish an instance of mongocxx 
    mongocxx::instance instance{};

    // Connect to MongoDB server 
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);
    
    // Access database UserData
    mongocxx::database db = client["UserData"];

    // Access the specific collection
    mongocxx::collection collection = db["Users"];

    // Query the collection and iterate over the documents
    auto cursor = collection.find({});
    
    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        // Print each document
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}

this code correctly print the following:
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "665d09b70296028f85120934"
},
"username": "Jake",
"password": "Hello"
}
I have another function and all I want to do is search the documents inside of collection "Users" that equal specific username.
void searchDataInMongoDBServer()
{
    cout << "Search MongoDB Connection" << endl;

    // establish instance of mongocxx
    mongocxx::instance instance{};

    // conect to mongo DB server as a client 
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);

    // Lets access a specific data base 
    mongocxx::database db = client["UserData"];

    // Now that we have access to the data base lets access a specific collectin 
    mongocxx::collection myCollection = db["Users"];

    // we now have access to the collection insdie of our database 
    // lets search for documents in the collection 
    
    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document query_builder;
    query_builder << "username" << "Jake";
    
    // Execute the query
    auto cursor = myCollection.find(query_builder.view());

    // Iterate over the results
    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}

The error I receive:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_base_of.h:22:94: **error**: incomplete type 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::stream::value_context<bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::stream::key_context<>>' used in type trait expression
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_base_of : public integral_constant<bool, __is_base_of(_Bp, _Dp)> {};

thes are libraries I have include in my main.cpp
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

below is the c_cpp_properties include path
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/",
                "/opt/homebrew/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongo-cxx driver/3.10.1/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/third_party/mnmlstc",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongo-cxx-driver/3.10.1/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/builder/stream"

Trying to build a query to search my mongoDB collection. but getting error: incomplete type

Cannot reproduce with that set of headers and code. Is this a compile error or a vscode error? How are you compiling?

Hey I am so sorry for this late reply, I found the issue! Basically in my main I was calling both function as shown below viewMongoDBServer(); and searchDataInMongoDBServer() right after another
the issue was that in both function I was creating a instance of MongoDB when I should only be doing it once.
